# backbone model save issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just started working on backbone a week ago, please don't mind if this question is silly. Alright, here's what I am trying to do.

I have a model called Item and a collection called Items. There are two views, one to add the item and the other to list the items. The issue I am having is when I am trying to save the item, it gets saved correctly for the first time. The next time when I add a new item, the item is created successfully, but the previous item added also gets updated with the attributes of the new item. This happens to all the successive items being added.

I am guessing that all my models in the collection are being updated OR I need to have my own save method. I actually am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I just want to save the model in question with the view, not all the models in the collection. Would really appreciate some pointers.

Link to the [demo](http://bbstarter-demo.herokuapp.com/#items/add).

### Item add/edit view

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'use!underscore',
  'use!backbone',
  'mustache',
  'models/item',
  'views/bootstrap',
  'text!templates/items/edit.mustache',
  'text!templates/items/new.mustache',
  'handlebars',
  'bootstrap'

], function($, _, Backbone, Mustache, Item, Bootstrap, editTemplate, newTemplate, Handlebars){

  var app = new Backbone.Router

  var ItemEditView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#page'),

    events: {
      'submit #new-item': 'saveItem',
      'click .cancel': 'cancelItem'
    },

    initialize: function(options){
      if (!this.model.isNew()) {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this)
        this.model.fetch()
      }
    },

    render: function(){
      var item = this.model.attributes
      var template = this.model.isNew() ? newTemplate : editTemplate
      var compiledTemplate = Mustache.render(template, item )
      $(this.el).html(compiledTemplate)
      if (this.model.isNew()) $('#itemName').focus()
      return this
    },


    /*
     *  Event actions
     */

    saveItem: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      var item = {
        name: $('#itemName').val(),
        price: $('#itemPrice').val()
      }
      var self = this
      this.model.save(item, {
        success: function (model, response) {
          app.navigate('items/'+model.id, {trigger: true, replace: true})
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
          new Bootstrap.alert({ el: $('#page') }).render(response, 'error')
        }
      })
    },

    cancelItem: function (e) {
      if (this.model.isNew())
        app.navigate('items', {trigger: true, replace: true})
      else
        app.navigate('items/'+this.model.id, {trigger: true, replace: true})
    }

  })

  return ItemEditView
})
```

### Item model

```
define([
  'use!underscore',
  'use!backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: 'api/items',

    idAttribute: '_id'

  });

  return Item;
});
```

### Items collection

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'use!underscore',
  'use!backbone',
  'models/item'
], function($, _, Backbone, Item){
  var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Item,

    url: 'api/items/'

  });

  return Items;
});
```

Link to the [Source code](https://github.com/madhums/bbstarter-demo) (in case)

Comment: It's not clear from the code you list here where you're adding new "items" to your items collection. One thing I would recommend is that you move model logic out of the view and into the model. If you need to update your model due to an event happening in your view, then just call a method on your model from your view that does the logic you need.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. The reason I haven't put the complete code is because its modularized, kept in different folders and files. Here's the link to the [complete code](https://github.com/madhums/bbstarter-demo) though

Comment: I don't need the link to the code so much as some direction as to where you're adding new "items" to your items collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are done using your form, either the form is submitted or canceled you must either destroy or the view by calling ItemView.remove() or at least un-delegate events::

```
saveItem: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  var item = {
    name: $('#itemName').val(),
    price: $('#itemPrice').val()
  }
  var self = this
  this.model.save(item, {
    success: function (model, response) {
      app.navigate('items/'+model.id, {trigger: true, replace: true})
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
      new Bootstrap.alert({ el: $('#page') }).render(response, 'error')
    }
  })
  this.remove(); // undelegate events for later views.
},

cancelItem: function (e) {
  if (this.model.isNew())
    app.navigate('items', {trigger: true, replace: true})
  else
    app.navigate('items/'+this.model.id, {trigger: true, replace: true});
  this.remove(); // undelegate events for later views.
}
```

As the events are delegated to #page and your old views exist after creating new ones their save and cancel methods will still trigger until they are removed.

Comment: I should add that you should likely have 1 ItemCollection and not recreate it every time you need it. Will save you round trips to the server. Other then that looking good so far!

Comment: hey thank you so much! That solved the problem! How are things like these handled normally? Removing the view from the DOM won't work all the time

Comment: I used `this.undelegateEvents();` instead of `this.remove()`